# How to find the min and max value for each year for an array of objects of historical price data

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, date, minmax

```
2800: {Date: '2022-01-14', Open: 514.48999, High: 522.570007, Low: 511.269989, Close: 520.599976, …}
2801: {Date: '2022-01-18', Open: 510.390015, High: 519.390015, Low: 504.980011, Close: 513.340027, …}
2802: {Date: '2022-01-19', Open: 516.47998, High: 528.919983, Low: 515.299988, Close: 516.580017, …}
2803: {Date: '2022-01-20', Open: 522.380005, High: 532.030029, Low: 509.640015, Close: 510.850006, …}
2804: {Date: '2022-01-21', Open: 508.5, High: 513.859985, Low: 499.269989, Close: 499.910004, …}
2805: {Date: '2022-01-24', Open: 491.070007, High: 520.429993, Low: 483.309998, Close: 519.659973, …}
2806: {Date: '2022-01-25', Open: 505.51001, High: 514.26001, Low: 500.01001, Close: 502.720001, …}
```

I have the following historical price data of ADBE spanning more than 10 years.  I am trying to get the min and max value every year according to their reporting date, period ending Nov each year.

I am trying to get the output in an array:
`[2010 min price, 2011 min price, 2012 min price ...]`

```js
const startDate = new Date("2010-12-01");
const endDate = new Date("2022-04-30");
    
const data2 = data.filter(a => {
    const date = new Date(a.Date);
      return (date >= startDate && date <= endDate);
    });
console.log(data)

    
function findMinMax(key) {
    const datas = data2.map((node) => node[key]);
        return {
          min: Math.min(...datas),
          max: Math.max(...datas),
        }
}
const checkit = findMinMax('Close')
```

As per the code, how can I do it without having to change the start and end date for each year just to get the min max value?

Comment: Please give an example of a sample input (condensed) and a sample output.

Comment: sorry not sure what input you are after? let input = [{Date: '2022-01-14', Open: 514.48999, High: 522.570007, Low: 511.269989, Close: 520.599976}, {Date: '2022-01-18', Open: 510.390015, High: 519.390015, Low: 504.980011, Close: 513.340027}]

Comment: And from this you want to calculate for every year what's the maximum & minimum values for "open", "high", "low" & "close"?

Comment: For any of them.  Just close is fine

Comment: Okay! Got it, I can help you with the same, can you provide a big dataset so that I test my solution?

Comment: sure where do i upload it?

Comment: Checkout my answer, if it doesn't solve your problem, then you can share your dataset, you can share it on something like JSBin.

Comment: thanks it works.  what if if the start date is not exactly the calender year.  For example, ending November

Comment: how do I get it to work for the year starting 1-December instead of beginning in 1-Jan?

Comment: sorry its not working.  What I mean is I want to calculate the min, max range for each year starting 1-December-Year to end-Nov-Year.  Currently it only works for 1-Jan-Year to end-Dec-Year

Comment: The OP doesn't mention this, please phrase your question correctly!

Comment: .... I am trying to get the min and max value every year according to their reporting date, period "ending Nov" each year.   Sorry if I did not make this very clear.  But I did mention it

Comment: I really do appreciate the time you have spent helping me.  I am new to javascript.  Thank you very much

Comment: Let's say the year is 2022, then you want to only look into dates from 1st Jan 2022 to 30th Nov 2022, right?

Comment: it is based on the reporting period.  So for this year 2022 it will be starting from 1-Dec-2021 to Today.  For the last reporting period it will be 1-Dec-2020 - end of Nov 2021

Comment: And where are you getting this reporting period from?

Comment: Their financial reports.  They report for the full year ending nov.  The months varies depending on the company's reporting period.  For adobe it is for the full year ending Nov.

Comment: Yup finally got you buddy, I've updated my answer to calculate based on the reporting year, you can checkout the solution. In my example `01-05-2022` will be considered in reporting year `2021-2022` and `01-11-2021` will be considered in reporting year `2020-2021`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the solution below it calculates min/max for all fields based on the reporting month.

```js
const data = [
  { Date: "2022-01-14", Open: 100, High: 500, Low: 50, Close: 1000 },
  { Date: "2021-12-05", Open: 200, High: 150, Low: 150, Close: 2000 },
  { Date: "2021-10-21", Open: 300, High: 550, Low: 70, Close: 200 },
  { Date: "2021-02-18", Open: 250, High: 600, Low: 10, Close: 500 },
];

const START_REPORTING_MONTH = 11; // 11 for December

const output = data.reduce((res, { Date: date, ...rest }) => {
  const d = new Date(date);
  const year = d.getFullYear();
  const month = d.getMonth();
  let reportingPeriod;

  if (month >= START_REPORTING_MONTH) {
    reportingPeriod = `${year}-${year + 1}`;
  } else {
    reportingPeriod = `${year - 1}-${year}`;
  }

  if (!res[reportingPeriod]) {
    res[reportingPeriod] = { min: { ...rest }, max: { ...rest } };
  }

  Object.entries(rest).forEach(([k, v]) => {
    if (v < res[reportingPeriod].min[k]) {
      res[reportingPeriod].min[k] = v;
    }
    if (v > res[reportingPeriod].max[k]) {
      res[reportingPeriod].max[k] = v;
    }
  });

  return res;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```